# CDLL can not find find shared object

Tags: python-3.x, shared-libraries

I have shared object file **libalgo.so** in /usr/lib. `ls -al /usr/lib` gives

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  14264 Jul  6 06:57 libalgo.so
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 403496 Oct  8 12:07 libnlopt.so.0
```

I have to import this shared library in python

```py
from ctypes import *
    try:
        lib = '/usr/lib/libalgo.so'
        algo_lib = CDLL(lib)
        print('algo_lib loaded')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

when running this code I get an error message saying could not read the shared object. No such file...

I have also added /usr/lib in LD_LIBRARY_PATH. This error only occurs in remote in which I am sshing into not in my local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR** The libalgo.so was compiled for arm.

We are developing for an arm system on x86 machines. One of the deb packages ended up with wrong shared object. Also error message given by python were misleading at best . instead of showing something like invalid object file , the message led me to believe that python could not find the file. I am not sure why such error message was given and any more information on this will be appreciated.